# Format timestamp from database to Java

Tags: java, oracle, date, format, timestamp

I have this weird format of date and time on my Oracle SQL Developer :

`2015-4-14.1.39. 33. 870000000`

I tried to format the given date to `MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss`, but it gives me exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-4-14.1.39. 33. 870000000"
```

The following is the code:

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

    try {
        String ts = "2015-4-14.1.39. 33. 870000000";
        Date date = formatter.parse(ts);
        String S = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(date);

        System.out.println(S);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: How is `formatter` defined/configured?

Comment: please share the declaration of `formatter`.

Comment: "MM/dd/yyyy" will not match "2015-4-14.1.39. 33. 870000000"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the given date string does not match the specified format. Try use the following format:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd.H.m. s. S");
String ts = "2015-4-14.1.39. 33. 870000000";
df.parse(ts);
```

Where

- `yyyy` for year
- `M` for month in year
- `dd` for day in month
- `H` for hour in date (0-23)
- `m` for minute in hour
- `s` for second in minute
- `S` for millisecond